# Can't access Dynamically created html elements from code behind

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

I have a page that has an unordered list on it. I am populating the list via javascript like this:

```
var vidList = document.getElementById("vidList");

var li = document.createElement("li");
li.id = "videoPlayer" + count;
var runat = document.createAttribute("runat");
runat.value = "server";
li.setAttributeNode(runat);
// Here I insert a flash video stream into li
vidlist.appendChild(li);
```

This works as far as creating the elements and rendering them to the page. The issue is accessing them later. Since they are video streams I want to remove them when they are no longer valid streams. In my Visual Basic code behind I have the following code:

```
For videoNumber As Integer = 1 to numVideos
    Dim li = vidList.FindControl("videoPlayer" & videoNumber.toString())
    // Check if the stream is valid and delete it if it isn't
Next
```

When I debug the call to `FindControl` returns `Nothing`. So I looked through the local variables and found that my list had 5 elements all of which are `Nothing`. I looked at both [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546315/asp-net-reading-dynamically-generated-html-element-value-in-codebehind) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351361/accessing-client-side-dynamic-controls-within-asp-net-codebehind), but neither quite worked for my needs. Is there a reason that the list items are coming into the code behind as null values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Request.Form['videoPlayer' + count]`

More generally you can use `Request.Form['clientID']` for dynamically created controls.